# whille creating a react app ,process stops and shows 1 vulnerablity (run npm audit)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

while running npx create-react-app app-name,process stops automatically at run npm audit fix and it doesn't show any error

i have also used different commands to solve this issue

`update npm globally`

`npm install -g create-react-app`

`create-react-app my-app`

or

`install yarn`

`yarn create react-app my-app`

or

`npm cache clean --force`

`npx create-react-app my-app`

but nothing worked for me ,it always stops at run npm audit vulnerablity

```
    PS D:\mern> npx create-react-app client    

Creating a new React app in D:\mern\client.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...


> core-js@2.6.11 postinstall D:\mern\client\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> core-js@3.6.5 postinstall D:\mern\client\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> core-js-pure@3.6.5 postinstall D:\mern\client\node_modules\core-js-pure
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

+ cra-template@1.0.3
+ react-scripts@3.4.1
+ react@16.13.1
+ react-dom@16.13.1
added 1626 packages from 750 contributors and audited 1630 packages in 257.371s

59 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can just run `npm audit fix` to try fix it.
Some projects do have 1 or more vulnerabilities, sadly, this is normal
In case `npm audit fix` doesnt help it, try `npm audit fix --force` instead.

[EDIT]
Also, as said on the command output:

> added 1626 packages from 750 contributors and audited 1630 packages in 257.371s

The packages are added, there's no error, just a alert about a vulnerability on one of the 1626 recently added packages.

So you can compile your project if you dont care about that one vulnerability.